# I am trying to create a URL but the URL must contain \r\n

Tags: objective-c

I have been beating my head against the wall with this one. The url must contain \r\n at the end or the device I am connecting to will not recognise it. I did not create the device so I can't go in and change what it is looking for. I also can not use the percent values for them either. When I create the URL from a string the URL becomes nil because it does not like the \r\n. I have searched on here all day. Literally and have come up with nothing. If anyone has a suggestion please let me know. I would really appreciate it.

Edit.. The url is @"http://192.168.1.1/link.html?cmd=scan\r\n"

Comment: Well, it isn't valid so... How are you intending to use it?

Comment: The thing is you can type it into a browser exactly like that and it works. But when you create a URL from String it doesn't like it with the \r\n. So what you are saying is it is not possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure out another way in so I did not have to send the string like that. Thank for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSLog(@"http://192.168.1.1/link.html?cmd=scan\\r\\n");
```

OutPut:

```
http://192.168.1.1/link.html?cmd=scan\r\n
```

You have to skip the "\" with just putting another "\".

Comment: I tried that earlier. Didn't work. Thanx for the input though.Its when it gets converted to a URL that it does no like it.  Sorry about the crappy formatting not sure how to make all nice.                                                api = @"http://192.168.1.1/link.html?cmd=scan\r\n";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",api]];
        
        NSString *response;
        NSError *error;
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];